# Can you help identify a strange Devanagari symbol in a book that doesn't look like any Devanagari letters?

Tags: sanskrit

In the book *Shaktapramode* ([example page](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.407147/2015.407147.Shaktapramod#page/n280/mode/1up)), there is a strange symbol 
[image: unfamiliar symbol] that I have never encountered before.

Here it is in the context: [image].

Does anybody know what it signifies? Thank you!

Comment: There is a proposal to create a Sanskrit stackexchange, you can follow it here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language?referrer=VB_DyRh7yEVCp82blVmACA2

Comment: This is a Daivanāgarī question, not a Sanskrit one. Sanskrit can be written in the Latin script, and will definitely lack this mark

Comment: Thank you for the correction and the unicode, @Darkgamma. I have edited the title to indicate that.

Answer (score 4):

The technical term for this symbol is called jihvamuliya. When a visarga is followed by either क/ख the visarga is replaced with this special symbol. It is pronounced with as "ahka/ahkha" with some amount of aspiration.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you, @linuxfan.

So if I were to type it in devanagari e.g. on a virtual keyboard like: [https://gate2home.com/Sanskrit-Keyboard] - I only see ':'  
  
How can I then correctly transliterate it in IAST? just use plain ḥ?  
  
Finally perhaps the info you shared can be added to: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visarga]? Thank you

Comment: I can't find the characters for jihvamuliya and upadhmaniya on the keyboard. I think publishers use a different set of characters to represent these sounds. Here's an image of how these are printed in my book: https://imgur.com/a/saubL I've seen other variants in other books as well.

Comment: Thank you, @linuxfan. I tried using ᳲ from [https://unicode-table.com/en/#1CF2] as suggested here by Darkgamma, but transliteration tools like [https://www.ashtangayoga.info/sanskrit/transliteration/transliteration-tool/#devanagari/iast/xn--l2bl5ayfz07j] don't know what to do with it and leave it untransliterated: e.g. मनस्ᳲ - manasaᳲ. For now I have just replaced it with normal visarga.

Comment: Leaving the visarga as-is in places such as कः करोति, कः पचति is technically correct. The sounds jihva-muliya and upadhmaniya are only relevant when reading the text. Representing them in text has little benefit other than making the reader alert that they should be enunciated differently.

Comment: Perfect. I much appreciated your supportive commentary, @linuxfan.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that this glyph is what Unicode calls **VEDIC SIGN ARDHAVISARGA** (seen [in this codepoint list](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1CD0.pdf) for the Vedic Extensions block). Despite its positioning in the Vedic Extensions block, its use is reportedly "not limited to Vedic."

Comment: Is that code 1CF2?

Comment: @Mitch appears to be so, yes